# SQL where statement with two conditions

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

I want to copy a column from a table to another column in another table with the condition of id in first table is equal id in the second one

please i want to know as possibile as you can if the syntax is right and if not how to correct it

thanks

```
INSERT offerte 
SET tipo_offerta = 
    (
      SELECT id_tipo
      FROM tipi_offerte
      WHERE id_tipo_offerta IN 
      (
        SELECT id_tipo_offerta
        FROM tipi_offerte
      ) = id_offerta IN 
      (
        SELECT id_offerta
        FROM offerte
      );
```

for example

```
    $tipi_offerte = array(
  array('id_tipo_offerta' => '5','id_tipo' => '3','id_offerta' => '5'),
  array('id_tipo_offerta' => '6','id_tipo' => '2','id_offerta' => '6'),
  array('id_tipo_offerta' => '7','id_tipo' => '2','id_offerta' => '7'),
  array('id_tipo_offerta' => '8','id_tipo' => '2','id_offerta' => '8'),
```

this is a part of the tipi_offerta table i'm going to use 
and 
here is the table i'm going to copy in

```
    $offerte = array(
  array('id_offerta' => '6','titolo' => 'Vinci un fantastico Barbecue Weber con Develey!','slug' => 'vinci-un-fantastico-barbecue-weber-con-develey','link' => 'http://concorsi.develey.it/','negozio' => 'Develey','data_scadenza' => '2016-09-30','slider' => '1','contenuto_riservato' => '0','contenuto_verificato' => '1','in_evidenza' => '0','pagina_dedicata' => '1','descrizione' => 'Acquista le seguenti salse a marchio Develey nel formato vaso vetro 250ml: Salsa Messicana, Salsa Greca, Salsa Barbecue e il prodotto Ketchup BBQ in confezione Squeeze 250ml tutte riportanti un fix-a-form con il logo pubblicitario del concorso, e conserva lo scontrino in originale di acquisto. Compila il form di registrazione con tutti i tuoi dati e inserisci quelli dello scontrino in originale.','seo_personalizzato' => '1','seo_titolo' => 'Vinci un fantastico Barbecue Weber con Develey!','seo_keyword' => 'Barbecue Weber','seo_descrizione' => 'Comprando alcuni prodotti Develey è possibile vincere un Barbecue Weber. Munirsi dello scontrino originale.','pubblicita' => '0','codice_sconto' => '','click' => '50','autore' => 'giuseppe','stato' => '10','data_inserimento' => '2016-06-22 15:03:34','data_aggiornamento' => '2016-09-06 14:46:03','visto' => '1','modificata_da' => NULL,'tipo_offerta' => NULL),
  array('id_offerta' => '7','titolo' => 'Scopri come vincere Buoni MediaWorld da 100€','slug' => 'scopri-come-vincere-buoni-mediaworld-da-100','link' => 'http://www.compagnidiviaggio-avventuristi.it/registrazione','negozio' => 'Allianz','data_scadenza' => '2016-09-15','slider' => '1','contenuto_riservato' => '0','contenuto_verificato' => '1','in_evidenza' => '0','pagina_dedicata' => '1','descrizione' => 'Registrati e rispondi ai questionari proposti per poter vincere Buoni MediaWorld da 100 euro! Per maggiori info consulta il regolamento.','seo_personalizzato' => '1','seo_titolo' => 'Scopri come vincere Buoni MediaWorld da 100€','seo_keyword' => 'Buoni MediaWorld','seo_descrizione' => 'Non farti scappare l\'occasione di vincere Buoni MediaWorld da 100€. Offerta valida fino al 15 luglio 2016.','pubblicita' => '0','codice_sconto' => '','click' => '16','autore' => 'giuseppe','stato' => '10','data_inserimento' => '2016-06-22 16:14:25','data_aggiornamento' => '2016-06-29 11:23:07','visto' => '1','modificata_da' => NULL,'tipo_offerta' => NULL),
  array('id_offerta' => '8','titolo' => 'Super Premi Estivi targati Maxibon: power bank, teli da mare e altro','slug' => 'super-premi-estivi-targati-maxibon-power-bank-teli-da-mare-e-altro','link' => 'https://www.buonalavita.it/maxibon/','negozio' => 'Nestlè','data_scadenza' => '2016-07-31','slider' => '1','contenuto_riservato' => '0','contenuto_verificato' => '1','in_evidenza' => '0','pagina_dedicata' => '1','descrizione' => 'Registrati e partecipa al concorso Maxibon per vincere i prodotti da mare della linea "Granella" o "Biscotto": avrai fino a 10 possibilità al giorno!','seo_personalizzato' => '1','seo_titolo' => 'Super Premi Estivi targati Maxibon: power bank, teli da mare e altro','seo_keyword' => 'Concorso Maxibon','seo_descrizione' => 'Con il concorso Maxibon è possibile vincere teli da mare, palloni, power bank, occhiali e magliette.','pubblicita' => '0','codice_sconto' => '','click' => '49','autore' => 'giuseppe','stato' => '10','data_inserimento' => '2016-06-22 16:15:35','data_aggiornamento' => '2016-06-29 11:22:44','visto' => '1','modificata_da' => NULL,'tipo_offerta' => NULL),
```

i want to copy **id_tipo**

```
 $tipi_offerte = array(
      array('id_tipo_offerta' => '5','`id_tipo`' => '3','id_offerta' => '5'),
```

in **tipo_offerta**

```
 ` $offerte = array(
      array('id_offerta' => '6','titolo' => 'Vinci un fantastico Barbecue Weber con Develey!','slug' => 'vinci-un-fantastico-barbecue-weber-con-develey','link' => 'http://concorsi.develey.it/','negozio' => 'Develey','data_scadenza' => '2016-09-30','slider' => '1','contenuto_riservato' => '0','contenuto_verificato' => '1','in_evidenza' => '0','pagina_dedicata' => '1','descrizione' => 'Acquista le seguenti salse a marchio Develey nel formato vaso vetro 250ml: Salsa Messicana, Salsa Greca, Salsa Barbecue e il prodotto Ketchup BBQ in confezione Squeeze 250ml tutte riportanti un fix-a-form con il logo pubblicitario del concorso, e conserva lo scontrino in originale di acquisto. Compila il form di registrazione con tutti i tuoi dati e inserisci quelli dello scontrino in originale.','seo_personalizzato' => '1','seo_titolo' => 'Vinci un fantastico Barbecue Weber con Develey!','seo_keyword' => 'Barbecue Weber','seo_descrizione' => 'Comprando alcuni prodotti Develey è possibile vincere un Barbecue Weber. Munirsi dello scontrino originale.','pubblicita' => '0','codice_sconto' => '','click' => '50','autore' => 'giuseppe','stato' => '10','data_inserimento' => '2016-06-22 15:03:34','data_aggiornamento' => '2016-09-06 14:46:03','visto' => '1','modificata_da' => NULL,'tipo_offerta' => NULL),`
```

where ***id_tipo_offerta*** is equal to **id_offerta**

Comment: About the syntax being correct, no, it's not.

Comment: You should add some examples because this attempt at sql does not make a lot of sense. To me at least.

Comment: so the error is in id_offerta IN (
 SELECT id_offerta
    FROM offerte); 
right ? what should i put in stand of that

Comment: @YassinGamal show some example so that we will know what are you trying to achieve exactly. That will be more clear to give you the suitable answer.

Comment: Maybe if you show the data structure involve in your query, plus saying clearly what you want to do (human like, not computer like), you'll be able to generate the algorithm to make what you want to achieve

Comment: @ Sushank Pokharel all what i'm trying to do is the simple thing that i post here ... i have already the db with the data i just want to copy it in another one

Comment: udpate your question ad   a proper  data sample  and the expcted result

Comment: @scaisEdge  the expect result is coping the  column in another one with the same data  but just associated to the same id

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code seems you need  an insert by select  based on a join between the tables  offerte and tipi_offerte

assuming that the tables  offerte and tipi_offerte are related  by id_offerta you  could use

```
insert into offerte (tipo_offerta, id_offerta)
select b.id_tipo, a.id_offerta
from offerte a 
inner join tipi_offerte b on a.id_offerta = b.id_offerta
```

but could be that your relation is base on a.id_tipo_offerta = b.id_tipo_offerta
in this case

```
insert into offerte (tipo_offerta, id_offerta)
select b.id_tipo, a.id_offerta
from offerte a 
inner join tipi_offerte b on a.id_tipo_offerta = b.id_tipo_offerta
```

but if the question is about updating a value in existing rows thenyou need  just an UPDATE

```
UPDATE offerte  a
inner join tipi_offerte b on a.id_offerta = b.id_tipo_offerta 
set a.tipo_offerta = b.id_tipo
```

Comment: thx for your answer i have updated my question so please look at it again it should be more clear now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right (really not sure about that), then this is what you are looking for:

```
UPDATE 
    offerte
SET 
    offerte.tipo_offerta = tipi_offerte.id_tipo
FROM 
    offerte
    INNER JOIN tipi_offerte
        ON offerte.id = tipi_offerte.id_tipo_offerta
```

This is assuming that in the table tipi_offerte the column `id_tipo_offerta` is the id of the offerte table

Comment: thx for your answer i have updated my question so please look at it again it should be more clear now